# Cannot understand properties of Conflict class of TFS version control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I tried to understand the conflict class of TFS version control from its documentation, but could not understand each properties with its' meanings.

Documentation link: [Conflict class (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb170292(v%3Dvs.120))

I need to understand the following properties:

1. BaseChangeType
2. BaseServerItem
3. TheirServerItem
4. YourChangeType
5. YourServerItem
6. YourServerItemSource

Suppose, I generate a conflict using TFS version control in the following way.

1. `Project/main/file.txt`
2. `Project/trunk/file.txt` [created a branch of main named trunk]
3. Rename file `Project/main/file.txt` to `Project/main/file-1.txt`
4. Edit file `Project/trunk/file.txt`
5. Merge `Project/main` to `Project/trunk`

After the 5th point, a conflict will be generated, as file has been renamed in the source(Project/main) and edited in the target(Project/trunk). Can you tell me which values the above properties will have if I try to get this conflict value from code. What will be the values of above property? It is also fine, if you can explain with another example.

Comment: Why don't you try the scenario in your question and then see what values each property has? I do stuff like that all the time when using a new library to familiarize myself.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Agreed, even I wanted to do the same, but I don't have the access to TFS at the moment, and I need to understand this for some other problem. Help me, if you know the answer. I'll surely try on my own, when I have the access.

Comment: @YashMehta dev.azure.com. You can create a free sandbox account for yourself to play with.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I assume `BaseChangeType` will be rename or something similar in this case, `YourChangeType` will be edit. The item will be the file. Just a guess.